# Question on the causal structure of free Dirac Field

Tags: quantum-field-theory, dirac-equation, causality

I am reading the paper by Casini, Huerta "Reduced density matrix and internal dynamics for multicomponent regions", https://arxiv.org/abs/0903.5284.

We consider the region $V$, to be a spatial curve in two dimensional Minkowski space. They say that equation (14)

$$ \Psi_i(x) = \int_V ds \left\{ \Psi_i(x), \tilde \Psi_j(s) \right\} \Psi_j(s) $$

is valid for any spacetime point $x$ in the domain of dependence of $V$ and $s$ is a distance parameter along $V$.

I can't see why this is valid just for the domain of dependence of $V$ and not for every $x$ in the spacetime. Evert comment is welcome!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the subject, but the naive guess is that $\int_V \delta(x-y)\mathrm dx=\begin{cases}1&y\in V\\0&y\neq V\end{cases}$, right?

Comment: I don't think I follow you. From what you said I understand that the right side of (14) is trivially zero for $x$ outside $V$, even if $x$ is in the domain of dependence of $V$ right?. I think the anticommutator on the right side is not in general the Dirac Delta, only if $x \in V$. In case $x \notin V$ the Dirac equation is satisfied in $x$ because the other elements work as constants for Dirac equation.